# Cordova Console Log when Beta Testing

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am interested to know if there is any tool to track the js console log of multiple devices for both ios and android.

Basically I am about to beta test my new cordova/ionic/angular app with beta testers and since they are quite a few I want to be able to check the console log of each and every device to see how the app is performing.

If such a tool is not available fire away ideas or current possible approaches you would take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your own Google Analytics and send whatever you want in it.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

For getting your messages:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$log

https://coderwall.com/p/_zporq/logging-in-angular-apps-and-how-to-filter-those-log-messages